# Related and non-related SQL queries putted together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two questions, one is how I can put these two queries together (add just the right column). Example:

```
Query 1
Phase  menCount
A      40
B      50
C      60
D      20

Query 2
Phase  womenCount
A      60
B      50
C      40

Wanted query result
Phase  menCount   womenCount
A      40         60
B      50         50
C      60         40
D      20         NULL
```

The second question is, how I can put together columns from non-related queries. Is this possible at all? I have at least 10 different srcripts and if I can put them into one call, it would be easier. Example:

```
Query 1
Phase  phaseCount
A      20
B      40
C      60

Query 2
Stage  stageCount
W      90
X      120
Y      150
Z      190

Wanted query result
Phase  phaseCount  Stage  stageCount
A      20          W      90
B      40          X      120
C      60          Y      150
                   Z      190
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: We need more details to answer your questions. Could you post actual queries and table definitions? Also why do you need result from second question? It seems unnatural for SQL (assuming queries operate on unrelated data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put two queries together you can treate them as "table expressions". For example

```
select
  coalesce(a.phase, b.phase) as phase,
  a.mencount,
  b.womencount
from (
  -- query #1 here
) a
full join (
  -- query #2 here
) b on a.phase = b.phase
```

To put unrelated queries together you need to produce a joining condition somewhere. For example, you can modify each query to produce an artificial row number using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function; then you can use this value to join against each other, as in:

```
select
  a.*, b.*
from (
  -- modified query #1 now
  select
    ...,
    row_number() over(order by ...) as rn
  from ...
) a
full join (
  -- modified query #2 now
  select
    ...,
    row_number() over(order by ...) as rn
  from ...
) b on a.rn = b.rn
order by coalesce(a.rn, b.rn)
```